# How do I "un-index" a type?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to understand how to "un-index".

Given:

```
type Example = {
    sayHi: {
        name: string;
    } | {
        sayHi: string;
    };
    cure: {
        bool: boolean;
    } | {
        cure: string;
    };
}
```

How do I get:

```
({name: string; } | { sayHi: string; }) & ({bool: boolean } | { cure: string })
```

I've tried but it flattens everything to a union.

```
type Example2 = Example[keyof Example]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a variation of [`UnionToIntersection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) that distributes over the keys of a type an intersects the property values:

```
type Example = {
    sayHi: {
        name: string;
    } | {
        sayHi: string;
    };
    cure: {
        bool: boolean;
    } | {
        cure: string;
    };
}


type UnionToIntersectionValues<U, K extends keyof U = keyof U> = 
    (K extends unknown ? (k: U[K]) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type R = UnionToIntersectionValues<Example>
// type R = ({
//     name: string;
// } & {
//     bool: boolean;
// }) | ({
//     name: string;
// } & {
//     cure: string;
// }) | ({
//     sayHi: string;
// } & {
//     bool: boolean;
// }) | ({
//     sayHi: string;
// } & {
//     cure: string;
// })
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=35&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQN4FgBQURUAzgiABICWAXDgcY1AHbIR0nABOVzA5gG4GxAL5QAPvUJMiZSrVLdeg4URFDpRAMYBXLuykyiAIwD2p1HTMWICZhsZjJeTU136OS-g9EaRBAPxQSCgAVWYqU2YAFVMASWZgCC4SCC1gSOYANQRUHQgSAB5QgBooAGkoCDgk5gATEigAawgQUwAzMKgsFrbO0IA+bqhVKAAKSurahqgdZibmUwB3ZigAfnGmulCAbXKAXQBKbqGAN1MqOqg6ZghT5OOpiHrGsbGtqF525Kg444wzhc6scNnFriw7slAsFoAAlYbhTKxBJJFJpDJRHJ5AqFeDINAQAYEAD0xKgMKg8KwYxcpKYrCQBk4PG8JLJYgAZFI6YxrJYoHzbPY2VARMdJDSRYwGUyvCp8HTOdyyYx3LKWfLFeLxrSVcQ5NRPBqNIqoFzdUw+VZzOg7Cb2drJQq9bJyIbFMaRUqLaq9OrlPbRYcgA)

**Note:** Ts will move the intersection inside and the union outside based on the equivalence that `(A | B) & (C | D)` is `(A & C) | (A & D) | (B & C) | (B & D)`, so  the type of `R` is equivalent to the type you are looking for.

Comment: This is really neat, I was trying to do the iteration over the keys with a recursive type which required union to tuple & was generally a much worse answer.

Comment: I'm having an issue with this where it returns unknown if the object is empty. I need to to just send `U` if it's unknown.

Comment: @ThomasReggi I think that can be handled in an extra check. something like `keyof U extends never ? "someDefaultType" : UnionToIntersectionValues<U>`